# Numerical PHP variables in MySQL queries

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to build a query in a script that relies upon an object's attributes in order to retrieve the correct information.  What I have is this:

```
$query = "SELECT fields FROM table WHERE fieldA  = $this->x";
//Processing of results here
```

I've seen queries like this used before with string variables but I'm not sure if the rules are different if you're using a variable that you know has a numerical value and the corresponding column for said value is declared as an integer or decimal.  Would I need to include single quotes around `$this->x`?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing

Comment: It's probably about time you started learning a little bit of SQL.... and then a little bit about prepared statements and bind variables

Comment: try: $query = "SELECT fields FROM table WHERE fieldA  = ".$this->x;

Comment: $this->x   this is enough in where it can be string or integer np

Comment: Please read related topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1

Comment: When you put the payload data into the sql query string (instead of using prepared statements) the MySQL server parses _that_ string, regardless of how it was constructed "within" php. `SELECT ... WHERE foo=1` is valid, no need for single quotes (though MySQL's implicit type casting could handle `foo='1'`). So, if you're absolutely certain $this->x contains only digits (always) you can do that, `"SELECT fields FROM table WHERE fieldA  = {$this->x}"`. On the other hand, why bother when there are almost fool-proof prepared statements+named parameters? ;-)

Comment: The thing about this is that this is part of an object and in the situation where this specific object gets created, no user input is taken.  Is a prepared statement still recommended or would it be more efficient to do it the way I initially intended?

Comment: I am not clear with your question. What is the problem you are facing ?

Comment: An object is created to display its corresponding database information on the page.  No user input is taken nor required in order to do this.  Should I still use a prepared statement in order to fetch the items' information from the database, or is it acceptable to use a standard string query and execute it with a mysqli database handler?

Comment: If you make selective judgements on the source of data to determine when you should and shouldn't use prepared statements/bind variables, you'll make a mistake (and you end up increasing code complexity having different methods to interact with the database in different circumstances).... be consistent, and always use prepared statements/bind variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said $this->x is numeric. I make a small test. Its working fine.

```
class foo{
    public $x; 
    public function showQuery (){
        $this->x = 10;
        return "SELECT fields FROM table WHERE fieldA  = $this->x";
    }
}
$ob = new foo();
echo $ob->showQuery();
```

OUTPUT :

```
SELECT fields FROM table WHERE fieldA  = 10
```

**Note** : It depends upon your wish you want to use PDO or not. is it acceptable to use a standard string query and execute it with a mysqli database handler? : YES

Answer (score 1):

Use PDO to do that:

```
$user     = "username";
$password = "password";

$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname', $user, $pass);

$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT fields FROM table WHERE fieldA = :value');
$stmt->execute(array('value' => $this->x);
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Print the result:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
echo '</pre>';
```

Or bind one value:

```
$sth->bindValue(':value', $this->x, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

For MySQLi see:
 [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1)